# Javascript keyup login form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a loginform using pure javascript (no libraries) and I have 2 problems!

**SOLVED! by Grainier Perera**

1. When username.value.length hits 4 characters usernameInfo.innerHTML changes back to "Please type ypur username" ! The problem is passwordInfo.innerHTML changes to "At least 6 characters" as soon as username.value.length hits 4 characters. So here is my first problem. I want passwordInfo.innerHTML to change only when I start typing in password field (onkeyup).
2. My second problem. When I submit the form with empty fields I want both usernameInfo.innerHTML and passwordInfo.innerHTML to change, not only usernameInfo.innerHTML.

To make it easier for u to understand the code I'll paste it all here so you can just copy it and try it yourself. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

form label {display:block; margin-top:5px;margin-left:3px;font:12px Arial;color:gray;}
form input {width:200px;padding:5px;display:inline-block; margin-top:5px;}
#submit {padding:7px;background-color:#f7af38;     border:#f7af38;width:215px;display:inline-block;margin-top:15px;font:11px Tahoma;color:black;}
#usernameInfo {display:inline-block; font:italic 12px Arial; color:gray;}
#passwordInfo {display:inline-block; font:italic 12px Arial; color:gray;}
#finalInfo {font:italic 12px Arial; margin-left:5px;}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return validate();">

    <label>Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" onkeyup="return validate();" /> 
    <span id="usernameInfo"></span>


    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" onkeyup="return validate();" /> 
    <span id="passwordInfo"></span>

     <br />

     <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
    <span id="finalInfo"></span>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('usernameInfo').innerHTML = "Please type your username!";
document.getElementById('passwordInfo').innerHTML = "Please type your password!";


function validate()
{
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var usernameInfo = document.getElementById('usernameInfo');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var passwordInfo = document.getElementById('passwordInfo');

    if(username.value.length < 4){
        usernameInfo.style.color='red';
        usernameInfo.innerHTML = "At least 4 characters!";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        usernameInfo.style.color='gray';
        usernameInfo.innerHTML = "Please type your username!";

    }
    if(password.value.length < 6){
        passwordInfo.style.color='red';
        passwordInfo.innerHTML = "At least 6 characters!";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        passwordInfo.style.color='gray';
        passwordInfo.innerHTML = "Please type your password!";
    }

}

</script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" onkeyup="return validateUserName();" />
    <span id="usernameInfo"></span>

    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" onkeyup="return validatePassWord();" />
    <span id="passwordInfo"></span>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
    <span id="finalInfo"></span>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('usernameInfo').innerHTML = "Please type your username!";
document.getElementById('passwordInfo').innerHTML = "Please type your password!";

function validateUserName()
{
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var usernameInfo = document.getElementById('usernameInfo');

    if(username.value.length < 4){
        usernameInfo.style.color='red';
        usernameInfo.innerHTML = "At least 4 characters!";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        usernameInfo.style.color='gray';
        usernameInfo.innerHTML = "Please type your username!";
        return true;
    }
}

function validatePassWord()
{
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var passwordInfo = document.getElementById('passwordInfo');

    if(password.value.length < 6){
        passwordInfo.style.color='red';
        passwordInfo.innerHTML = "At least 6 characters!";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        passwordInfo.style.color='gray';
        passwordInfo.innerHTML = "Please type your password!";
        return true;
    }
}

function validateForm()
{
    var userValid = validateUserName();
    var passValid = validatePassWord();
    return userValid && passValid;
}
```

Working Sample : [link](http://jsbin.com/ciwaw/1)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. This solved my first problem but now when I submit the form with empty fields no error appears. All i want now is to prevent the form for submiting if any error and print them. Thanks again

Comment: I did some updates to the code. I checked it locally, and It worked just fine.

Comment: Did you checked the sample I shared in my answer? [link](http://jsbin.com/ciwaw/1)

Comment: Oh i see..well i checked your sample and it seems your code is fine. That is exactly what i want to achieve but for some reason whenever i press submit it sends me to login.php and can;t figure out why :\

Comment: check this line `<form method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">` it should have 'onsubmit="return validateForm();"'

Comment: OK I am very sorry. I was refreshing the wrong copy lol. Sorry for missleading you. Your code works exactly how I wanted! You inspire me to learn more and get better! Thank you!! :D